# Is it true that for any $v\in \Bbb R^n$ we have $||Av||\le ||v||$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that all eigen values of $A$ are less than $1$,then is it true that for any $v\in \Bbb R^n$ we have $||Av||\le ||v||$.

Since $A$ has eigen value less than $1$ so if $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$ then $Av=\lambda v\implies ||Av||<||v||$ but how to use this fact for any $v\in \Bbb R^n$.

Any help will be useful.

Comment: What about $\pmatrix{1&10\\0&1}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown;eigenvalue is $1$ here

Comment: @Learnmore You can make a small modification for an answer.

Comment: Replace $1$ with $0.5$@LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Relation between spectral radius and largest singular value

$$\max_{i}|\lambda_i|\leq \sigma_1$$

- Relation between largest singular value and induced norm

$$\sigma_1=\max_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{||Av||}{||v||}$$

- Can you find an example where spectral radius is less than 1 and largest singular value is greater than 1?

Answer (score 0):

If the eigenvectors form a basis, then for any $v$, you can write it as a linear combination of eigenvectors. If the eigenvectors are orthogonal, you can use this to prove the result.

However, it doesn't work otherwise. Are you told that $A$ is symmetric, by any chance?